# What GUI Linux programs are there for finding files based upon their contents?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gui

What GUI Linux programs are there for finding files based upon their contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome Search Tool is a built-in GUI tool available from **Places -> Search For Files**. Internally, it uses locate, find and grep to perform the search.

Answer (score 1):

[Beagle](http://beagle-project.org/Main_Page) indexes a lot of formats.

Comment: best indexer ever!!!!

Answer (score 0):

GNOME Commander

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Commander

Answer (score 0):

Google Desktop works very nicely in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

gnome-do is handy, quick, and has many useful extensions